# I have to solve $a-b$ without calculating $a$ and $b$. So whats is $a-b$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

It is given that $a+b=2$, $ab=-3$ and $a<b$. The answer is $-4$ but I do not know how to do it

Comment: $a-b = -\sqrt{(a-b)^2} = -\sqrt{(a+b)^2-4ab}$. How is this related to algebraic topology?

Comment: You should be asking yourself, "Do I know any identities in which $a+b$, $ab$, and $a-b$ appear?" The answer should be: "I know $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$ and $(a-b)^2=a^2-2ab+b^2$." Subtracting the equations tells you $$(a+b)^2-(a-b)^2=4ab$$ You can now solve for $a-b$: $(a-b)^2=(a+b)^2-4ab$. There are two solutions for $a-b$ in general, one positive and one negative, but if $a<b$ the solution is unique: it's the negative one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(a+b)^2 - 4ab = a^2 - 2ab -b^2 = (a-b)^2$

$(a-b)^2 = 2^2 - 4*-3 = 16$

$a-b = +/-4$

Since $b>a$, $a-b < 0$.
Thus, $a-b = -4$.

Comment: Please use MathJax